# Bluetooth Low Energy on Android 5.0 refreshes data from Beacons not as good as on Android 4.4

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working on application to cooperate with Beacons. Yesterday I updated my nexus 4 from Android 4.4 Kitkat to Android 5.0 Lolipop. Today I was writing code and I saw that my application, which worked good on 4.4, now has problems with data refresh. It refreshes data very slow and loses connection after 1-2 minutes. Beacon is maximum 1 meter next to my phone.

Is there known issue on android 5.0 Lolipop with BLE or I should for example install clean system again on my phone, not updating 4.4?

Now simple instruction like below is sometimes not working.

```
beacons.get(0).getName());
```

I wrote this to get name of first beacon nearby and sometimes it gives value null.

Application which worked on 4.4 now has problems on 5.0.

Anyone with similar problem after installing new android 5.0?

Thanks for your help,
Jakub